# Getting the action's tag name within the action

Tags: php, actions

There's a function attached to a set of actions, like this:

```
add_action('some_tag', 'the_function');

function the_function($maybe_some_vars){
  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to find out the action name ("some_tag") within the_function?

The reason I'm asking, is that I'm attaching the function to multiple actions (some of them custom, some belong to WP like `the_content`). The code that executes within the function depends on knowing the name of the action.

I did manage to get it using [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), but I'm pretty sure that's not a very reliable way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: [`current_filter();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_filter) ([link to plugin.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/plugin.php#L306)) or `global $wp_current_filter;`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about it and didn't think about using it! :)

Comment: n/p. We all got moments where we simply forget about the obvious stuff. :)